# When does Picasso refresh image cache

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, picasso

I am using picasso to fetch images from server.

This is what i am using.

```
            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(imageURL)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.card_loading)
                    .fit().centerCrop()
                    .into(imageView);
```

The above code should `cache` the images, but when i update the same image on server, without changing its `URL`, it starts displaying the new image on app, whereas it should display the `cached` old image on the app.

In some devices it was displaying the older images, i closed and restart the app multiple times, then it started displaying the new images on those devices as well.

My Question is that how long `picasso` keep an image in cache, and how can i increase this from server or client

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how long cache file valid. But you can change cache file validity with incoming http response header. Basically you can create interceptor and add new header with "Cache-Control" name.

```
 OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    httpClient.networkInterceptors().add(new Interceptor(){

        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(chain.request());
            return originalResponse.newBuilder().header("Cache-Control", "max-age=" + (60 * 60 * 24 * 365)).build();
        }
    });
```

After that you can pass it to picasso as a http client

Comment: Thanks `gokhan`

Should i pass the httpClient to picasso like this;

`Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(context)
        .downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(client))
        .build();`