# Does glide also uses http header to cahce images

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, picasso, android-glide

I am using `Picasso` to load image in my app. As mentioned [here](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/1558), *The disk cache is maintained by the HTTP client, not Picasso*.

I want to keep images in cache forever, unless user removes it or delete the app. I don't want to perform network operation each time.

My question is does Glide uses some other mechanism to cache images, or it also uses `http`

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49651984/4977669), If i need to provide cahce implementation in `picasso`, i need to use `okhttp`.

Do i also need to do the same for `Glide` or it takes care of `Caching`

Comment: Glide has it's own documentation about Caching it will give you detailed answer please refer to this link . https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/caching.html

Answer (score 0):

From official `Glide` [docs](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/configuration.html#disk-cache),

> By defualt, the cache is placed in a specific directory in the Application’s cache folder. Applications can change the location to external storage if the media they display is public (obtained from websites without authentication, search engines etc).

You can do it like this :

```
@GlideModule
public class YourAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {
    @Override
    public void applyOptions(Context context, GlideBuilder builder) {
    builder.setDiskCache(new ExternalDiskCacheFactory(context));
    }
  }
```

You can customize the cache folder name like this:

```
   @GlideModule
   public class YourAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {
       @Override
       public void applyOptions(Context context, GlideBuilder builder {

       /**You can set cache size here**/
       int diskCacheSizeBytes = 1024 * 1024 * 100; // 100 MB

       builder.setDiskCache(
       new InternalDiskCacheFactory(context, "cacheFolderName", diskCacheSizeBytes));
       }
   }
```